# Why is MapReduce in CouchDB called "incremental"?

Tags: data-structures, couchdb, mapreduce, terminology

I am reading the O'Reilly CouchDB book. I am puzzled by the reduce/re-reduce/incremental-MapReduce part on page 64. Too much is left to rhetory in the O'Reilly book with the sentence

> If you're interested in pushing the ede of CouchDB's incremental reduce functionality, have a look at Google's paper on Sawzall, ...

If I understand the word *"incremental"* correctly, it refers to some sort of addition -operation in the B-tree data structure. I cannot yet see why it is somehow special over typical map-reduce, probably not yet understanding it. In CouchDB, it mentions that there is no side-effects with map function - does that hold true with reduce too?

Why is MapReduce in CouchDB is called "incremental"?

#### Helper questions

1. Explain the quote about incremental MapReduce with Sawzall.
2. Why two terms for the same thing i.e. reduction? Reduce and re-reduce?

#### References

1. A Google paper about [Sawzall](http://research.google.com/archive/sawzall.html).
2. [Introduction to CouchDB views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) in the CouchDB wiki and a lot of blurry blog references.
3. [CouchDB O'Reilly book](http://guide.couchdb.org/)

Comment: ...I am not sure yet what is the purpose of term but I have some vague ideas, perhaps related to the replication, the data-structure or the logic how mapreduce works -- investigating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views) page that you linked explained it.

The view (which is the whole point of map reduce in CouchDB) can be updated by re-indexing **only the documents that have changed since the last index update.** That's the incremental part.

This can be achieved by requiring the reduce function to be referentially transparent, which means that it always returns the same output for a given input.

The reduce function also must be commutative and associative for the array value input, which means that if you run the reducer on the output of that same reducer, you will receive the same result. In that wiki page it is expressed like:

```
f(Key, Values) == f(Key, [ f(Key, Values) ] )
```

Rereduce is where you take the output from several reducer calls and run that through the reducer again. This sometimes is required because CouchDB sends stuff through the reducer in batches, so sometimes not all keys that need to be reduced will be sent through in once shot.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add slightly to what user1087981 said, the reduce functionality is incremental because of the way the reduce process is performed by CouchDB.

CouchDB uses the B-Tree that it creates from the view function, and in essence it performs the reduce calculations in clumps of values.  Here's a very simple mockup of a B-Tree from the [O'Reilly Guide](https://guide.couchdb.org/) showing the leaf nodes for [the example in the section you quoted from](https://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#reduce).

[image: Reduce B-Tree]

So, why is this incremental?  Well, the final reduce is only performed at query time and all the *reduce* calculations are stored in the B-Tree view index.  So, let's say that you add a new value to your DB that is another `"fr"` value.  The calculations for the 1st, 2nd and 4th nodes above don't need to be redone.  The new `"fr"` value is added, and the reduce function is re-calculated only for that 3rd leaf node.

Then at query time the final (`rereduce=true`) calculation is performed on the indexed values, and the final value returned.  You can see that this incremental nature of reduce allows the time taken to recalculate relative only to the new values being added, not to the size of the existing data set.

Having no side-effects is another important part of this process.  If, for example, your reduce functions relied on some other state being maintained as you walked through all the values, then that might work for the very first run, but then when a new value is added and an incremental reduce calculation is made it wouldn't have that same state available to it - and so it would fail to result in the correct result.  This is why reduce functions need to be side-effect free, or as user1087981 puts it *"referentially transparent"*

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between `"reduce"` and `"rereduce"`? Are they the same operation in different location such as leaf or parent?